# How to find the difference of two lists including how they're ordered

Tags: python, list

I've set up some code here:

```
L1 = [4, 1, 4, 2, 6, 7, -1, 15, 1, 18, 42, 51]
L2 = [4, 1, 4, 3, 6, 10, -1, 15, 2, 18, 42, 51, 92, 16, 41]

d = 0


d = [i for i in L1 if i not in L2]

L3 = abs(len(L1)-len(L2))

print("The lists have", len(d) + L3, "differences.")
```

And the output is "The lists have 4 differences."

But I'm supposed to get 6 differences because the order of the numbers in the lists matter. And if one list is longer than another, how much longer it is is also supposed to be considered a difference.

If index 1 has "2" in list 1, and index 1 has "3" in list 2, that's supposed to be considered a difference even if both lists have "2" and "3".

I just really don't know how to make it do that.

Comment: Deleting your question, deleting your account, making a new account, and asking the same low-quality [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325911/how-to-find-number-of-differences-in-a-list) a second time is not likely to make people more willing to write code for you.

Comment: I apologize for that. But I've made an attempt and I've shown you my code. If you don't want to help that's fine.

Comment: It looks like you might be able to use `zip`, or maybe `itertools.zip_longest`. But it's not entirely clear what counts as one difference. Is inserting a value a single difference, or does it make all the subsequent values different too (e.g. how many differences are there between `[2, 3, 4]` and `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, one or four)?

Comment: There'd be four. 
They need to be the same number in the same index to be considered the same. And if one list is longer than another, how much longer it is is considered a difference.

Comment: Your question looks related to the "sequence alignment" problem that is at the basis of many bioinformatics algorithms. You may find inspiration by looking at sequence alignment algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to solve this for you, but you can do this stuff -- give yourself a chance and think through what it is you need to do.

```
# initializations
L1 = [4, 1, 4, 2, 6, 7, -1, 15, 1, 18, 42, 51] 
L2 = [4, 1, 4, 3, 6, 10, -1, 15, 2, 18, 42, 51, 92, 16, 41]

# get the min and max sizes
min_len, max_len = min(len(L1), len(L2)), max(len(L1), len(L2))

# initialize differences to the absolute difference in length
differences = max_len - min_len

# for every ith item in the list, increment differences by 1 if it isn't equal
# to the ith item in the other list
for i in range(0, min_len):                                   
    if L1[i] != L2[i]:
        differences += 1

# print it out
print("The lists have", differences, "differences.")
```

*Ask yourself some questions about what I wrote -- why did I do the min and max first? Why, in the for loop did I use the min_len as the upper bound in the range? ;)*